# How do I measure the effect of a Dummy variable on a Dependant variable?

Tags: r, regression, panel, dummy-variable

I have data consisting of 4 years worth of NFL games along with their attendances, TV ratings and many other variables. I want to look at the impact the National anthem protests in 2016 had on attendances and tv rating. How would I go about seeing what impact a dummy variable, protest, had on the attendances for these years?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: do a statistical test to measure the ratings before and ratings after. paired t-test. I'm guessing attendance wasn't affected since there is a capacity at each stadium. Attendance will probably be reflected on team's records, if it even shows an effect at all. But rating would be interesting to see. My hypothesis is there was no significant difference. lots of links if you google search R paired T-test [link1](http://www.statstutor.ac.uk/resources/uploaded/paired-t-test.pdf), [link2](https://www.r-bloggers.com/paired-students-t-test/)

Comment: Thanks for the response, will definitely look into this. Is there any way to do it as a regression model as the project is asking for an empirical model. In terms of a regression model for attendance ive done some research and it seems a tobit regression is good for as it uses censored variables, such as a stadium capacity. Just not sure how to interpret results from this as an impact of protests, as protests is just measured as a dummy variable

Comment: To estimate the marginal effect of an independent variable, a linear probability model is preferred over its nonlinear counterparts, such as logit, tobit, or probit. Although it gives nonbinary predictions, its coefficient estimate is unbiased. BUT what you are asking is a very broad question. You will need to be careful with what independent variables to put in your regression.